# Is there a way to immediately know that the last trade (or a specific trade) has been closed, so we can place some new trades at that specific moment?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there a way to immediately know that the last trade (or a specific trade) has been closed, so we can place some new trades at that specific moment? (I don't want to wait for my position to be opened until the next candle is created.)

Actually, assuming I'm doing a "long" trade, I want to open some trades (say my last trade) again, if the price hits SL with a long shadow and it comes back up again on that very candle. In this case, the moment it hits SL I just want to place the buy order again. (It'll be a "stop order".)

Thanks.